# Action taken by compiler to limit the memory pointed by a pointer

Tags: c

In this code (keeping strict aliasing aside for a while):

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {   
     int i=10;
     void *ptr=&i;
     printf("%lu\n",sizeof(ptr));
     printf("%d\n",*(int *)ptr);
     return 0;
 }
```

It gives `sizeof(void*)` as **8**, but when it has been dereferenced after typecasting it to `int*` it exactly prints the number assigned to variable *i*.

How does compiler push/limit pointer of size 8 bytes to point to next 4 bytes (`sizeof(int)` on my system)?

Comment: Do you want `int i[2] = {0, 42}; void *p = i; printf("%d\n", *(((int *)p) + 1));`

Comment: @pmg I just want to get a rough map of things which happen inside.

Comment: "how does compiler pushes/limits pointer of size eight bytes to point to next four bytes (size of int on my system)" The size of a pointer on your system has nothing to do with the size of the object it points to.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking. Did you expect it to print something else?

Comment: There's no strict aliasing issue here to keep aside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 8 bytes is to save the address of the "i" (int i =10;) in the memory, so it doesn't mean what kind of data you want to save, it just saves the address memory location and it required 8 bytes to suit any data type that need to cast